# How do I search an array for just the number part to capture it into another char array?

Tags: arrays, c, integer

I am using C language,

If I have a char array of:

`www.google.com 20200929094403`

where the numbers fit the format of YYYYMMDDhhmmss are the fixed length of numbers, but the length of site could vary.

*How do I search that array for just the number* part to capture it into another char array?

I know in c# there is a parseInt function for the command line. But I am not familiar with the c version

edit 1: I am not authorized to use regex, sed, or bash scripts. this is the only part that's holding me up in finishing my proxy program for retrieving a file

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there will be no numbers previous to the first number you can just go down a for loop until the character is equal to something between 0x30 and 0x39 (ascii for 0-9)

Then you can use `strcpy( destination , &(source[where you found first digit]))`

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the number sequence is fixed and always at the end of your char array, you could store the address pointing to the beginning of the date like this :

```
char* date = src + (strlen(src) - 14);
```

With `src` containing the source payload and 14 being the length of `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`

Answer (score 0):

```
char inputCharArray[]=" www.google.com 20200929094403";
char outputCharArray[100];
int i;

int j = 0;

  
for(i=0; inputCharArray[i];i++){
if(inputCharArray[i] >= '0' && inputCharArray[i] <= '9'){
outputCharArray[j] = inputCharArray[i];
j++;
}
}

  
printf("Output: ");
printf("%s\n",outputCharArray);
```

I got it Thank you for your help!